# How can I allow a non-domain user to make changes to domain files?

Tags: dns, user-controls, user-profile

I am having what I believe is a permissions issue.

I have a user that has Windows 7 Home Edition and I need her to be able to access a folder that is controlled by the Domain, even though I cannot put her on the domain.

I have tried mapping the network drive using alternative credentials and even though she can gain access, she cannot add a new folder, which is truly the most important task to her.

I spoke to a friend of mine and he had me try to do:

```
net use T: \\EWS\MPC_DB$\quotes /user:mpc\administrator Password
```

and I kept getting a 'System Error 1219'

So I tried:

```
net use T: \\192.168.1.54\MPC_DB$\quotes /user:mpc\administrator Password
```

and viola, it appeared in her mapped network directory, however upon accessing the folder and trying to create a new folder she was met with an error message stating she did not have sufficient privileges.

I know beyond a shadow of a doubt that mpc\administrator has the necessary privileges to execute this action, but I am at a loss with how to get this task complete.

Comment: Perhaps, MPC\Administrator has right for accessing this share, but does not have sufficient rights on a folder level or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working.

In the event anyone else ever runs into a similar issue I will post my solution.

I kept on getting error messages so what I ended up doing was unmapping all the drives that I had connected to the computer in question and then mapped the drive I was after using credentials and everything went through just fine.

After this I remapped all the drives I had disconnected and everything seems to currently be in order.